# transfer from java to C#

Tags: c#, java

I want to transfer this part of java code to C# but I have get stucked in that:

```
public class PCComm {
      private SerialConnection sc;

public String systemfaults() {
  if ( (sc == null) || !sc.open) {
       return ("Serial communication not established");
       } 

   return ("OK");
  }
}
```

The Error for the (!sc.open) is that : Serialconnection.open is inaccessible due to its protection level

I changed the "Private" access level to "protected" level. Does it make sense ?

---

Edition:

I changed the code based on the comments that I got:

```
   public class PCComm {
          public readonly static int OPEN = 0;
          private SerialConnection sc;


   public PCComm() {
   }

    public String systemfaults() {
      if ( (sc == null) || !sc.open) {
           return ("Serial communication not established");
           } 

       return ("OK");
      }
    }
```

Still I get error in (sc.open)...

Comment: No it doesn't, a) you should provide definition of SerialConnection class, b) if you change it to protected, it is still not going to be accessible, you have to change it to public.

Comment: Thanks...I edited the code but still I get error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `protected` will not make the fields of `SerialConnections` available to external classes. You can either make the `open` field public:

`public boolean open`

or define a method, like this:

```
public boolean isOpen(){
    return this.open;
}
```

Comment: I can not vote you up because I do not have enough reputation :(

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right field? You have to change the `open` instance field in `SerialConnection` class. Even if I advise against making the field public, it's better to implement the accessor method `isOpen`.